# How Can I produce meta tag strings in PHP

Tags: php, tags, echo, meta

I'd like to produce my meta tag lines in php and then echo them in the  of the page.  I seem to be having problems.  When I echo the variable it actually echo's on screen rather than be contained to view source only like the other meta tags.

```
$ogmeta = '&lt;meta property="og:type" content="Article" /&gt;';
```

then I was just doing

```
echo $ogmeta;
```

I also tried

```
$ogmeta = htmlspecialchars('<meta property="og:type" content="Article" />');
```

Each time it echos to screen :(

EDIT:

I found this to work

```
$ogmeta = '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'" />'; 
echo $ogmeta;
```

But I need to have multiple entries for $ogmeta like this:

```
$ogmeta = '';
$ogmeta .= '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'" />';
$ogmeta .= '<meta property="og:site_name" content="some site" />';
$ogmeta .= '<meta property="og:type" content="Article" />';
$ogmeta .= '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$which_article.'" />';
```

When I tried echoing this it all appeared on a single line.  I tried adding a line break
but that doesnt work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you putting it in the head of the site? I know it sounds like a simple thing but must make sure

Comment: Yes, it's in the <head>

Comment: Then you will probably need to try it as the actual < >. Failing that, just populate the content instead of the whole tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `<something>` to be treated as a *tag*, then represent `<` and `>` as `<` and `>` (which are the HTML characters for start of tag and end of tag) and not as `&lt;` and `&gt;` (which are the HTML entities for less than and greater than).

```
$ogmeta = '<meta property="og:type" content="Article">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this. Inserting your **PHP** inside the **`<meta>`** tags too.

```
<?php
$metaKeywords="books,cars,bikes";
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<title>SomePage</title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo 'somedescription' ?>"></meta>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $metaKeywords ?>"></meta>
</head>
```

EDIT:

**Solution 1:** Make use of **`HEREDOC`**, Its pretty easier.

```
<?php
$metaTag=<<<EOD
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<title>SomePage</title>
<meta name="description" content="my description here"></meta>
<meta name="keywords" content="cars,bikes,books"></meta>
</head>
EOD;
echo $metaTag;
?>
```

**Solution 2:** You can also embed variables inside the **`HEREDOC`**.

```
<?php
$metaDesc="this is new";
$metaKeywords="cars,bikes,thrills";
$metaTag=<<<EOD
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<title>SomePage</title>
<meta name="description" content=$metaDesc></meta>
<meta name="keywords" content=$metaKeywords></meta>
</head>
EOD;
echo $metaTag;//Don't forget to echo
?>
```

Comment: I want to have the whole meta line <meta property="og:type" content="Article"> reoresented by a single variable.  I tried $ogmeta = '<meta property="og:type" content="Article">'; but it doesnt escape the < and >.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ogmeta = "property='og:type' content='Article'";


<meta <? echo $ogmeta; ?> />
```

Could do that?

Leave the meta tag always there and just fill in the gaps.

Next best:

```
$ogmeta = "<meta property='og:type' content='Article' />";

echo "$ogmeta";
```

This should work.

Comment: I had thought of that, but there will be some instances when the ogmeta variable is empty.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter but the next best thing would be (I will edit my post)

Comment: Originally I had the meta line in single quotes.  Yu suggest double quotes.  Does that a difference?